# Power Rangers-style show where the characters could morph using cards

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a TV show on a non-kids channel (I don't mean an adult one, but nothing similar to Cartoon Network) where the protagonist and enemies could transform using morphing cards.

The show **didn't** have a kids theme like *VR Troopers* or *Genseishin Justirisers*. The morphing process was like *[this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWY8FlMn6A4)* from *Power Rangers Megaforce*.

From my memories, I can tell the show isn't too old; I watched it like 8-10 years ago. If someone knows the show or has an idea, it would be really helpful. **<3**

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you certain this wasn't a different _Power Rangers_ series? Also, did the actors appear to be Western or Asian?

Comment: Was it live-action or animated? Digimon Tamers or Digimon Frontiers spring to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Could it have been Kamen Rider [Ryuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen_Rider_Ryuki)/[Dragon Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen_Rider:_Dragon_Knight)?

In the series, the Riders use Advent Decks, decks of special cards to both Transform and to activate special attacks.

Ryuki was dubbed into English Power Rangers style; which is to say they used props and footage from the Japanese version, but shot new scenes with English actors and altered the plot.

Both versions feature the concept of a world on the other side of mirrors and reflective surfaces.  And there were both hero and villain Riders in the series, so both sides were using the Advent Decks to transform.

Did the show you remember involve a lot of motorcycles?

Answer (score 1):

Might this be [*Tensou Sentai Goseiger*](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Tensou_Sentai_Goseiger) with their [Gosei cards](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Gosei_Cards)?

[image: Box cover art for Tensou Sentai Goseiger]

> The Gosei Cards (ゴセイカード Gosei Kādo) allow the Goseigers to perform Tensou Techniques (天装術 Tensō Jutsu). All of the Gosei Cards, when placed in the Tensouder, are activated with the activation call "Tensou!" These cards are routinely used for various purposeses by the Goseigers and Gosei Knight during *Tensou Sentai Goseiger*.
>
> It comes in various types: Mecha, Battle, and Transform. Each card holds a different power and these cards are very helpful. Once the card is placed in the Tensouder or the Knight Power Releasement Vessel Leon Cellular, it will activate the effect of the card like: summoning their weapons, use for different attacks, summoning their mecha, and transforming to the Goseigers and Gosei Knight. The Gosei Cards also appeared during their transformation and the show's eyecatch.

It was a 2010 series, the footage of which was used for *[Power Rangers Megaforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Rangers_Megaforce)* in 2013.

### Episode Previews showing them using the cards

Found with a search for `sentai show "use cards"` after a few other abortive attempts.